# Read GDB from C#

Tags: gdal, c#, file-geodatabase

I am trying to read .gdb file using osgeo API I go for following code but can't read, please suggest to me a solution.

```
string File= @"D:\GDB File\Demo.gdb";    
public IConnection OpenFDOSourceConnection(string File)
        {          
            IConnectionManager FDOManager = FeatureAccessManager.GetConnectionManager();                    
            IConnection FDOConnections = FDOManager.CreateConnection("OSGeo.Gdal.3.9");        
            OSGeo.FDO.Connections.IConnectionInfo connInfo = FDOConnections.ConnectionInfo;
            OSGeo.FDO.Connections.IConnectionPropertyDictionary connPropDict = connInfo.ConnectionProperties;           
            OSGeo.FDO.Connections.ConnectionState Constate;
            Constate = FDOConnections.Open();
            return FDOConnections;
        }
```

Comment: have you read file?